# string length validation error in tinymce textarea in opencart php

Tags: php, validation

In my HTML form, there's is a `textarea` and I want to add a validation into it. The validation comes like this, `textarea` should have more than three letters, otherwise, this should show an error message.

Here is the validation part (2nd IF condition for the `textarea`)

```
foreach ($this->request->post['information_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
        if ((utf8_strlen($value['title']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($value['title']) > 64)) {
            $this->error['title'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_title');
        }

        if (utf8_strlen(trim($value['description'])) < 3) {

            $this->error['description'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_description');

        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($value['meta_title']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($value['meta_title']) > 255)) {
            $this->error['meta_title'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_meta_title');
        }
    }
```

But the matter is that the `tinymce` HTML thing has a small HTML code already so the string length already exceeds the letter minimum amount. therefore this validation is not working.

Can someone tell me a solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the tinymce HTML **editor**'s html code is constant, just adjust the string length of the validation code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's strip_tags function (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp) in your validation. In this case it will only check the input text without the html tags.

tinymce will send `<p>lorem ipsum</p>` and when you use `strip_tags($value['meta_title'])` at your validation code validation will only check the length of `lorem ipsum`.

Hope this helps.